# Encrypt the song url in flex audio player

Tags: apache-flex, url, encryption

HI am new to AMFPHP. am creating flex audio player.
Whenever am playing the song in my player. the song url will be displayed by the use of FIREBUG addons..
How can i encrypt and decrypt that url using AMFPHP or PHP.
Some flash audio players done this job using AMFPH..
Edit/Delete Message

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Firebug's Net tab sees all HTTP[S] net traffic. If you want to stream a song to the browser without an HTTP URL being visible in Firebug, you would have to use a different protocol to HTTP — typically RTMP.

The way some sites protect HTTP streams is to use a one-time URL, so that the player generates an authentication token (typically using crypto hashing) and that can only be used to download the stream once; it is served with `Cache-Control: no-cache` header to stop the browser storing it on disc and making it available to the user for download from the Net tab. Defeating caching of course does mean that you'll serving a lot more data unnecessarily. And it's still pretty easy to circumvent.

Don't imagine you can solve the Copy Protection Problem. Even “protected” RTMPE is very much downloadable.

Comment: i want to restrict the song location by the use of encryption and decryption. it's possible. 
http://www.purevolume.com/handmedownbuick 
check this player you are not able to access(download) the song from server by the use of FIREBUG addons.

Comment: That is an example of the ‘one-time-URL’ approach. There is no encryption/decryption involved. I can easily download the song by tactics likes running by browser through a web proxy that saves files as it goes (a couple of lines of Python).

Comment: Dear bobince

Can you clarify me for another query? 

I have an ISP 123.125.12.12. I can ban the Ip as whole. but i need to ban a single computer in that IP. Can you Please let me know how to do it in PHP.

Comment: You might file that as a separate question. But no, you can't detect when a computer is behind a NAT or proxy, or which of several computers behind the same is in use, unless there are other distinguishing marks such as a cookie or a particular User-Agent string.